# Match different pattern in a string

Tags: regex

I want to remove all the captured elements from an initial string. So for instance, given the string

`https://item.taobao.com/item.htm?spm=a230r.1.999.1.11cf523cXZ0Yh3&id=564725808226&ns=1#detail`,

I want the following

`item.taobao.com/item.html?id=564725808226`

I have the following regular expression `(https:\/\/)|(spm=.*&(?=id))|(&ns=.*)` which behaves as follow : http://rubular.com/r/hp6xgB6pJ4

```
Match 1
1.  https://
2.   
3.   
Match 2
1.   
2.  spm=a230r.1.999.1.11cf523cXZ0Yh3&
3.   
Match 3
1.   
2.   
3.  &ns=1#detail
```

The thing is, I am not really satisfied with it because, as you can see, it yields three group of three, some of them have empty fields and it's not that convenient to perform a string operation for each of these match group.

Is there a way to get gather all the "matching" into one group match, so the output would look like

```
Match1
1. https://
2. spm=a230r.1.999.1.11cf523cXZ0Yh3&
3. &ns=1#detail
```

Comment: Just use your regex in a regex replace method and replace with an empty string.

Comment: But the regex works :) Instead of captruing the matches, replace them with an empty string. Check it here, as Regex101 also shows substitution. *In other terms*: this regex catches unneeded parts of the link instead of the ones u want. [Regex101 LINK](https://regex101.com/r/52obXZ/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the following

```
https:\/\/([\w\W.]+\/[\w\W.]+[?]).*(id=\d+)
```

You will have to combine group 1 and group 2 matches manually though

```
Full match  0-81    `https://item.taobao.com/item.htm?spm=a230r.1.999.1.11cf523cXZ0Yh3&id=564725808226`
Group 1.    8-33    `item.taobao.com/item.htm?`
Group 2.    65-81   `id=564725808226`
```

Answer (score 0):

As the comments told you you can already replace the unwanted stuff with empty strings, but if you want to reduce the number of matches as desired you can use:
`(https:\/\/).*?(spm=.*?&(?=id)).*?(&ns=.*)`. and then just replace the groups. Check http://rubular.com/r/mysRxjeiin

and your groups would be:

```
1.  https://
2.  spm=a230r.1.999.1.11cf523cXZ0Yh3&
3.  &ns=1#detail
```